# Como forçar a ocorrencia de um evento a partir de um método de extensão?

Tags: c#, .net, eventos, extension-method

Estou criando uma aplicação em C# e estou usando a interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` assim:

```
public class Test: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int foo;
    public int Foo { get => foo; set => Set(ref foo, value); }

    public void Set<T>(ref T property, T value, [CallerMemberName]string p = "")
    {
        property = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    }

}
```

Meu problema é que, sempre que eu quiser implementar essa forma de trabalho (com o método `Set(ref property, value)` eu sou obrigado a vir aqui e copiar o código e reimplementá-lo. A partir deste problema, eu pensei em um método de extensão assim:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public static class Extensions 
{
    public static void Set<T>(
        this INotifyPropertyChanged source, ref T property, T value,
        [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
    {
        property = value;
        source.PropertyChanged?
            .Invoke(source, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Meu problema é que se eu tento fazer essa implementação, eu recebo essa mensagem:

> The event `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

O que preciso fazer para que eu consiga forçar a chamada desse evento através de uma propriedade de extensão?

Comment: Tentou chamar como `this.`? Ou sem a sintaxe de extensão e chamar o método estático de forma normal, até passando o `this`?

Comment: Hmm não tentei... Vou fazer aqui, 1 mim...

Comment: Realmente não dá... se eu jogo um `this` ali ele entende que estou tentando referenciar a classe estática `Extensions`. Eu teria que chamar o evento dentro de source

Comment: Porque você não faz uma classe base, digamos, `MyPropertyChanged`, implementa a função `Set` nela e quando você precisar, ao invés de implementar `INotifyPropertyChanged` você herda de `MyPropertyChanged` onde já existe a função `Set` definida. Assim que geralmente é feito nos modelos MVVM onde você tem um `BaseViewModel` onde você implementa somente uma vez o `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não tenho a menor ideia do que está querendo fazer, até porque não tem a implementação completa, parece algo muito errado, mas pra estritamente resolver seu problema tem que passar o manipulador do evento como parâmetro para o método desejado e chamar explicitamente. Na verdade não vi vantagem em ter isso como método de extensão.

Tive que por algumas outras coisas para satisfazer a interface:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var x = new Test();
        x.Foo = 10;
    }
}
public class Test: INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private int foo;
    public int Foo { get => foo; set => this.Set(ref foo, value, PropertyChanged); }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name) {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}

public static class Extensions {
    public static void Set<T>(
        this INotifyPropertyChanged source, ref T property, T value, PropertyChangedEventHandler handler, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "") {
        property = value;
        handler?.Invoke(source, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/gIv9vE). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/za4qrN). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/CallEventExtern.cs).

Comment: a idéia era tentar criar globalmente uma forma de gerar estruturas observáveis sem que eu tenha que ficar reescrevendo código muitas vezes...